# Is it possible to run multiple Zookeeper instances with different port on single machine?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to start two zookeeper instances required for kafka cluster on two different ports with different log directories. However I'm getting below error when I'm trying to start second zookeeper -

> D:\Kafka\kafka_2.12-2.3.0 - Copy>bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties
>   Unrecognized option: -
>   Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Are there any logs written when you run it? Have you tried it without spaces in the folder name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to copy folders, only `zookeeper.properties` and you should never run only 2 ZKs anyway

Regarding the error, `Unrecognized option: -`... Don't copy folders, like I said, and make sure there are no spaces in the path to Zookeeper scripts

Note: this setup is highly discouraged even with separate directories because your failure domain is still that OS / machine. Kafka only requires a minimum of one Zookeeper to function

Comment: Hi cricket, I agree to your point to just copy the zookeeper.properties. But I'm wondering  what is the difference if I copy the whole folder instead. I'm more interested knowing what is causing this issue. As you can see, I'm doing this on windows machine.

Comment: Like I said, there's a space and dash in the path. If you've started one Zookeeper okay, then use the same folder structure for the next

Comment: Hi cricket, Thank you. It worked removing the spaces.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Zookeeper recommends 3 instances, on different machines.  However, if you only have one server, would it still be wise to have multiple instances running on it? The docs seem to suggest that one possible failure mode is file corruption - wouldn't having (at least) two instances protect against that?  Or would this suggestion be a silly, unnecessary, paranoid step?

Comment: @Remi One host can still have a corrupted volume. Are you suggesting using two physical disks on one host as well?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Not suggesting anything.  Just trying to wrap my mind around the risks involved of using Zookeeper on a system that is installed entirely on a single server.